# Node error _xdl(...).ProjectUtils.readConfigJsonAsync is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, react-native, expo

After installing expo-CLI Version 3.5.0 to my computer so that I'm able to use it and then running npm start Node throws this error:" _xdl(...).ProjectUtils.readConfigJsonAsync is not a function. " I cannot find the solution to this online, it appears to be a new issue. Is anyone else running into this or have a solution for successfully running the program?

Comment: `expo-cli@3.5.0` should work now, there was an issue with a package that it depended on having a breaking change in a minor version update. Out of curiosity, why are you using `expo-cli@3.5.0` rather than the latest version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also got the same issue. You don't need to downgrade node, just need to change some hashes on your project. (worked on node version 13.2.0 and expo-cli version 3.9.0 for me, although I have noticed that it also worked on  LTS node  12.13.1 )

You can change the file located at:

```
\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js
```

From :

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

To:

```
 var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

Answer (score 0):

*I need a solution as well. i have been using 3.5.0 version but today i tried to update it by mistake and i couldnt find a way yet to make it run normally. im starting to think the problem is server side or something updated is not compatible with old 3.5.0 version.
_xdl(...).ProjectUtils.readConfigJsonAsync is not a function
[Screenshot of the error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3qj1.png)*

**Edit:** i just found the solution. new version of the xdl causes the error.
**Fix:**

Open up a command prompt(if you are on a windows machine), no matter which directory you are at, type commands below

```
npm uni -g --no-save @expo/xdl
npm i -g --no-save @expo/xdl@56.8.0
```

if you don't specify what version you want to install, npm or yarn will immediately select 56.8.1 version and installs automaticly and causes the error.

you need to downgrade to 56.8.0 version by typing the commands that i gave above.

Comment: are you using expo-cli@3.5.0?

Comment: Yes, expo-cli 3.5.0 and node 12.10.0.

Comment: in your project folder rename the node_modules folder to anything else, open terminal in the project folder and just run> npm install

Comment: I tried your advice (renaming node_modules and running npm install). Still doesn't work.

Comment: it was worth to try. Last thing that i can recommend you is to create another project by "expo init projectName" and delete everything except node_modules and copy from your original project folder. These are the things that worked for me in past

Comment: Can I use older version of expo-cli (and which one) to work around this? This seems to be the problem with newer versions.